# What do I put in the compile file to optimize laravel

Tags: php, optimization, laravel-4

I'm optimizing my Laravel application as the overall response time is madly slow. On average on a page all my sql queries take close to 80ms to run but the entire response time for the page is over 4 seconds. I did some benchmarking and its apparent that the framework is the culprit here - over 400 files beings loaded on every page load.

I found that I could speed up the framework by adding files that were on every page load into the compile file and run an `artisan optimize` command. However I'm not sure what set of files do I have to include here as in. I tried to include every file I see in my laravel debug bar, even part of those files but at times some error happens the compiled file has its share fo errors namely because most files that do not have namespaces they are appended to blank namespaces.

Point being I'm pretty stumped right now - and really need to bring the response time of my application down drastically. My application runs on Laravel 4.2.

I've disabled as many unnecessary libraries as I can but it still doesn't have much of an impact.

I've just tried this on my compile file but it gives errors stating that a certian class cannot be redeclared. So i go and remove the file including that class only to find out another class has been redeclared. Isnt there a less painful way to do this?

```
<?php

return array(


'vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/S3/Command/S3Command.php',
'vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/S3/SseCpkListener.php',
'vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Client/UploadBodyListener.php',
'vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/S3/S3Md5Listener.php',
'vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/S3/AcpListener.php',
'vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/S3/BucketStyleListener.php',
'vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Iterator/AwsResourceIteratorFactory.php',
'vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Client/UserAgentListener.php',
'vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Exception/ExceptionListener.php',
'vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Exception/ExceptionFactoryInterface.php',
'vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Exception/NamespaceExceptionFactory.php',
'vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Signature/SignatureListener.php',
'vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Aws.php',
'vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Credentials/CredentialsInterface.php',
'vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Credentials/Credentials.php',

'vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/RulesEndpointProvider.php',
'vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Client/ClientBuilder.php',
'vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Signature/SignatureInterface.php',
'vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/S3/S3SignatureInterface.php',
'vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/S3/S3Signature.php',
'vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Client/ExpiredCredentialsChecker.php',
'vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/S3/SocketTimeoutChecker.php',
'vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/S3/IncompleteMultipartUploadChecker.php',
'vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Enum.php',
'vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Enum/ClientOptions.php',
'vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Exception/Parser/ExceptionParserInterface.php',
'vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Exception/Parser/DefaultXmlExceptionParser.php',
'vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/S3/Exception/Parser/S3ExceptionParser.php',
'vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Client/AwsClientInterface.php',
//'vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Client/AbstractClient.php',
'vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/S3/S3Client.php',







    'vendor/imagine/imagine/lib/Imagine/Image/ImagineInterface.php',
    //'vendor/imagine/imagine/lib/Imagine/Image/AbstractImagine.php',
    'vendor/imagine/imagine/lib/Imagine/Gd/Imagine.php',








//'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Command/LocationVisitor/Request/AbstractRequestVisitor.php',

'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Command/LocationVisitor/Request/ResponseBodyVisitor.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Command/LocationVisitor/Request/QueryVisitor.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Command/LocationVisitor/Request/RequestVisitorInterface.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Command/LocationVisitor/Request/HeaderVisitor.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlHandle.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Message/Header/HeaderInterface.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Message/Header.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Message/Header/HeaderCollection.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Message/Header/HeaderFactoryInterface.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Message/Header/HeaderFactory.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Message/RequestInterface.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Message/MessageInterface.php',
//'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Message/AbstractMessage.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Message/Request.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/QueryString.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Parser/UriTemplate/UriTemplateInterface.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Parser/UriTemplate/UriTemplate.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Parser/ParserRegistry.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Url.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Command/LocationVisitor/VisitorFlyweight.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Command/RequestSerializerInterface.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Command/DefaultRequestSerializer.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Description/ValidatorInterface.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Description/SchemaValidator.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Common/Event.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Description/Parameter.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Description/OperationInterface.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Description/Operation.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Command/Factory/AliasFactory.php',
//'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Resource/AbstractResourceIteratorFactory.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Resource/ResourceIteratorClassFactory.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Resource/ResourceIteratorFactoryInterface.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Inflection/MemoizingInflector.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Inflection/InflectorInterface.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Inflection/Inflector.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Command/Factory/ConcreteClassFactory.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Command/Factory/ServiceDescriptionFactory.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Command/Factory/FactoryInterface.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Command/Factory/CompositeFactory.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/QueryAggregator/QueryAggregatorInterface.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/QueryAggregator/DuplicateAggregator.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlVersion.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Common/Version.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Message/RequestFactoryInterface.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Message/RequestFactory.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/RedirectPlugin.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/ConfigLoaderInterface.php',
//'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/AbstractConfigLoader.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Description/ServiceDescriptionLoader.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Description/ServiceDescriptionInterface.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Description/ServiceDescription.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Common/ToArrayInterface.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Plugin/Backoff/ExponentialBackoffStrategy.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Plugin/Backoff/HttpBackoffStrategy.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Plugin/Backoff/CurlBackoffStrategy.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Plugin/Backoff/BackoffStrategyInterface.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Plugin/Backoff/TruncatedBackoffStrategy.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMultiInterface.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Plugin/Backoff/BackoffPlugin.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Common/FromConfigInterface.php',
'vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Common/HasDispatcherInterface.php',




'vendor/codesleeve/stapler/src/Interfaces/Storage.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/stapler/src/Storage/S3.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/stapler/src/Factories/Storage.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/stapler/src/Interfaces/Attachment.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/stapler/src/Attachment.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/stapler/src/Interfaces/Resizer.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/stapler/src/File/Image/Resizer.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/stapler/src/Interfaces/Interpolator.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/stapler/src/Interpolator.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/stapler/src/Interfaces/Style.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/stapler/src/Style.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/stapler/src/AttachmentConfig.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/stapler/src/Interfaces/Validator.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/stapler/src/Validator.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/stapler/src/Factories/Attachment.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/stapler/src/ORM/EloquentTrait.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/stapler/src/ORM/StaplerableInterface.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/stapler/src/Interfaces/Config.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/stapler/src/Stapler.php',

'vendor/codesleeve/laravel-stapler/src/IlluminateConfig.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/laravel-stapler/src/Providers/ServiceProvider.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/laravel-stapler/src/Providers/L4ServiceProvider.php',


'vendor/codesleeve/sprockets/src/Codesleeve/Sprockets/Directives/DependOn.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/sprockets/src/Codesleeve/Sprockets/Directives/Stub.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/sprockets/src/Codesleeve/Sprockets/Directives/IncludeTree.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/sprockets/src/Codesleeve/Sprockets/Directives/IncludeDirectory.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/sprockets/src/Codesleeve/Sprockets/Directives/IncludeFile.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/sprockets/src/Codesleeve/Sprockets/Directives/RequireSelf.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/sprockets/src/Codesleeve/Sprockets/Directives/RequireTreeDf.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/sprockets/src/Codesleeve/Sprockets/Directives/RequireTree.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/sprockets/src/Codesleeve/Sprockets/Directives/RequireDirectory.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/sprockets/src/Codesleeve/Sprockets/Interfaces/DirectiveInterface.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/sprockets/src/Codesleeve/Sprockets/Directives/BaseDirective.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/sprockets/src/Codesleeve/Sprockets/Directives/RequireFile.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/sprockets/src/Codesleeve/Sprockets/Interfaces/ClientCacheInterface.php',





'vendor/codesleeve/asset-pipeline/src/Codesleeve/AssetPipeline/Composers/ImageComposer.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/asset-pipeline/src/Codesleeve/AssetPipeline/Composers/StylesheetComposer.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/asset-pipeline/src/Codesleeve/AssetPipeline/Composers/ComposerInterface.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/asset-pipeline/src/Codesleeve/AssetPipeline/Composers/BaseComposer.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/asset-pipeline/src/Codesleeve/AssetPipeline/Composers/JavascriptComposer.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/asset-pipeline/src/Codesleeve/AssetPipeline/Filters/ClientCacheFilter.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/asset-pipeline/src/Codesleeve/AssetPipeline/Filters/JST.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/asset-pipeline/src/Codesleeve/AssetPipeline/Filters/SassFilter.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/asset-pipeline/src/Codesleeve/AssetPipeline/Filters/LessphpFilter.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/asset-pipeline/src/Codesleeve/AssetPipeline/Filters/CssMinFilter.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/asset-pipeline/src/Codesleeve/AssetPipeline/Filters/CoffeeScript.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/asset-pipeline/src/Codesleeve/AssetPipeline/Filters/JSMinPlusFilter.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/asset-pipeline/src/Codesleeve/AssetPipeline/Filters/EnvironmentFilter.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/asset-pipeline/src/Codesleeve/AssetPipeline/Filters/FilterHelper.php',
'vendor/codesleeve/asset-pipeline/src/Codesleeve/AssetPipeline/Filters/URLRewrite.php',

'vendor/codesleeve/asset-pipeline/src/Codesleeve/AssetPipeline/AssetPipelineServiceProvider.php',    





    'vendor/creitive/breadcrumbs/src/Creitive/Breadcrumbs/Breadcrumbs.php',
    'vendor/creitive/laravel4-breadcrumbs/src/Creitive/Breadcrumbs/BreadcrumbsServiceProvider.php',


    'vendor/laravelbook/ardent/src/LaravelBook/Ardent/Builder.php',
    'vendor/laravelbook/ardent/src/LaravelBook/Ardent/Ardent.php',    


    'vendor/ryannielson/meta/src/RyanNielson/Meta/Meta.php',
    'vendor/ryannielson/meta/src/RyanNielson/Meta/MetaServiceProvider.php',    


    'vendor/rmasters/culpa/src/Culpa/BlameableObserver.php',    


    'vendor/kalnoy/nestedset/src/Collection.php',
    'vendor/kalnoy/nestedset/src/QueryBuilder.php',
    'vendor/kalnoy/nestedset/src/Node.php',

    'vendor/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable/src/Cviebrock/EloquentSluggable/SluggableTrait.php',
    'vendor/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable/src/Cviebrock/EloquentSluggable/SluggableInterface.php',
    'vendor/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable/src/Cviebrock/EloquentSluggable/SluggableServiceProvider.php',




    'vendor/schickling/backup/src/Schickling/Backup/Console.php',
    'vendor/schickling/backup/src/Schickling/Backup/DatabaseBuilder.php',
    'vendor/schickling/backup/src/Schickling/Backup/BackupServiceProvider.php',


'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Providers/TinkerServiceProvider.php',
'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Providers/ServerServiceProvider.php',
'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Providers/RouteListServiceProvider.php',
'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Providers/PublisherServiceProvider.php',
'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Providers/OptimizeServiceProvider.php',
'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Providers/MaintenanceServiceProvider.php',
'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Providers/KeyGeneratorServiceProvider.php',
'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Providers/ComposerServiceProvider.php',
'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Providers/CommandCreatorServiceProvider.php',
'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Providers/ConsoleSupportServiceProvider.php',
'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Providers/ArtisanServiceProvider.php',




'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.php',
'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/MorphOneOrMany.php',
'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/MorphOne.php',
'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Relation.php',
'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.php',
'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/JoinClause.php',
'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.php',
'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php',
'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/SeedServiceProvider.php',
'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/MigrationServiceProvider.php',
'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php',
'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Processors/Processor.php',
'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Processors/MySqlProcessor.php',
'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Grammar.php',
'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php',
'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/MySqlGrammar.php',
'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/ConnectionInterface.php',
'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php',
'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/MySqlConnection.php',
'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/ConnectorInterface.php',
'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php',
'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php',




    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/Presenter.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/BootstrapPresenter.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/Paginator.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/Factory.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/PaginationServiceProvider.php',



    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Form.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/URL.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Lang.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Auth.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Queue.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/DB.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Session.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Pluralizer.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Cache.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Request.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Input.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/ViewErrorBag.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Event.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Config.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Response.php',





    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/UserProviderInterface.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthServiceProvider.php',



    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Hashing/HasherInterface.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Hashing/BcryptHasher.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Hashing/HashServiceProvider.php',


    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/SyncJob.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/QueueInterface.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Queue.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/SyncQueue.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Connectors/ConnectorInterface.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Connectors/SyncConnector.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/QueueManager.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/QueueServiceProvider.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/FailConsoleServiceProvider.php',















    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/CommandsServiceProvider.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/ExistenceAwareInterface.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/DatabaseSessionHandler.php',

    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/Repository.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/StoreInterface.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/FileStore.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/CacheManager.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/CacheServiceProvider.php',



    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/CompilerInterface.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/Compiler.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Factory.php',


    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php',












    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Html/HtmlBuilder.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Html/FormBuilder.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Html/HtmlServiceProvider.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/PresenceVerifierInterface.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/DatabasePresenceVerifier.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Factory.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/ValidationServiceProvider.php',


    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Translation/Translator.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Translation/LoaderInterface.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Translation/FileLoader.php',
    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Translation/TranslationServiceProvider.php',














    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/DecryptException.php',

    'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Exception/PlainDisplayer.php',





    'vendor/dingo/api/src/Auth/Authenticator.php',
    'vendor/dingo/api/src/Auth/ProviderInterface.php',
    'vendor/dingo/api/src/Auth/AuthorizationProvider.php',
    'vendor/dingo/api/src/Auth/BasicProvider.php',
    'vendor/dingo/api/src/Dispatcher.php',
    'vendor/dingo/api/src/Routing/ControllerReviser.php',
    'vendor/dingo/api/src/Event/RevisingHandler.php',
    'vendor/dingo/api/src/Routing/UrlGenerator.php',
    'vendor/dingo/api/src/Transformer/TransformerFactory.php',
    'vendor/dingo/api/src/Transformer/TransformerInterface.php',
    'vendor/dingo/api/src/Transformer/FractalTransformer.php',
    'vendor/dingo/api/src/Http/ResponseFormat/ResponseFormat.php',
    'vendor/dingo/api/src/Http/ResponseFormat/JsonResponseFormat.php',
    'vendor/dingo/api/src/Http/Response.php',
    'vendor/dingo/api/src/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php',
    'vendor/dingo/api/src/Routing/GroupCollection.php',
    'vendor/dingo/api/src/Properties.php',
    'vendor/dingo/api/src/Routing/Router.php',
    'vendor/dingo/api/src/Provider/EventServiceProvider.php',
    'vendor/dingo/api/src/Provider/FilterServiceProvider.php',
    'vendor/dingo/api/src/Provider/RoutingServiceProvider.php',
    'vendor/dingo/api/src/Provider/PropertiesServiceProvider.php',
    'vendor/dingo/api/src/Provider/ApiServiceProvider.php',






    'vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Formatter/FormatterInterface.php',
    'vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Formatter/NormalizerFormatter.php',
    'vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Formatter/LineFormatter.php',



    'vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Cache/CacheInterface.php',
    'vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Cache/FilesystemCache.php',
    'vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Filter/ScssphpFilter.php',
    'vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Filter/DependencyExtractorInterface.php',
    'vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Filter/LessphpFilter.php',
    'vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Filter/FilterInterface.php',
    'vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Filter/BaseCssFilter.php',




    'vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Cloner/Stub.php',
    'vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Cloner/Cursor.php',
    'vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Cloner/Data.php',
    'vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Event.php',
    'vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcherInterface.php',
    'vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php',
    'vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventSubscriberInterface.php',
    'vendor/symfony/routing/Symfony/Component/Routing/CompiledRoute.php',
    'vendor/symfony/routing/Symfony/Component/Routing/RouteCompilerInterface.php',
    'vendor/symfony/routing/Symfony/Component/Routing/RouteCompiler.php',
    'vendor/symfony/routing/Symfony/Component/Routing/Route.php',
    'vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Cloner/DumperInterface.php',
    'vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Dumper/DataDumperInterface.php',
    //'vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Dumper/AbstractDumper.php',
    'vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Dumper/CliDumper.php',
    'vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Cloner/ClonerInterface.php',
    //'vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Cloner/AbstractCloner.php',
    'vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Cloner/VarCloner.php',
    'vendor/symfony/translation/Symfony/Component/Translation/TranslatorInterface.php',
    'vendor/symfony/security-core/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Util/StringUtils.php',
    'vendor/symfony/security-core/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Util/SecureRandomInterface.php',
    'vendor/symfony/security-core/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Util/SecureRandom.php',







    'vendor/darsain/laravel-console/src/Darsain/Console/Console.php',
    'vendor/darsain/laravel-console/src/Darsain/Console/ConsoleServiceProvider.php',



    'vendor/psr/log/Psr/Log/LogLevel.php',
    //'vendor/psr/log/Psr/Log/AbstractLogger.php', 


    'vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/ImageServiceProviderLaravel4.php',
    'vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/ImageServiceProvider.php',



    'vendor/chrisbjr/api-guard/src/Chrisbjr/ApiGuard/ApiGuardServiceProvider.php',


    'vendor/sammyk/laravel-facebook-sdk/src/LaravelFacebookSdk/LaravelFacebookSdkServiceProvider.php',


    'vendor/zizaco/entrust/src/Entrust/EntrustServiceProvider.php',
    'vendor/zizaco/confide/src/Confide/ServiceProvider.php',


    'vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Carbon.php',
    'vendor/jenssegers/date/src/Jenssegers/Date/Date.php',






    'vendor/league/fractal/src/Manager.php',


    'vendor/stevebauman/location/src/Stevebauman/Location/Objects/Location.php',

    'vendor/anhskohbo/no-captcha/src/NoCaptchaServiceProvider.php',
    'vendor/maatwebsite/excel/src/Maatwebsite/Excel/ExcelServiceProvider.php',

    'vendor/milon/barcode/src/Milon/Barcode/BarcodeServiceProvider.php',
    'vendor/themonkeys/error-emailer/src/Themonkeys/ErrorEmailer/ErrorEmailerServiceProvider.php',
    'vendor/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel/src/Artdarek/OAuth/OAuthServiceProvider.php',
    'vendor/adamwathan/bootforms/src/AdamWathan/BootForms/BootFormsServiceProvider.php',



    'vendor/ellipsesynergie/api-response/src/Laravel/ResponseServiceProvider.php',
    'vendor/jenssegers/date/src/Jenssegers/Date/DateServiceProvider.php',


    'vendor/stevebauman/location/src/Stevebauman/Location/LocationServiceProvider.php',


    'vendor/filp/whoops/src/Whoops/Handler/PrettyPageHandler.php',



    'vendor/patchwork/utf8/src/Patchwork/Utf8/Bootup.php',




    );
```

I know its a ginormous file - but have pretty much run into a wall here.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have an answer to your question, but a suggestion: www.blackfire.io
With this tool you can 'see' which part or what files in your app are taking up so much time. I hope you find something!